Calulate person per minute with input list of time's
In this project I get the time's people enter a queue.
queue.append(time.time())
When someone leaves I remove the last element from the list.
queue.pop(0)
I am trying to calculate the average people per minute that enter and leave (2 seperate data).
This is an example of 5 people in the queue:
[1735671309.570244, 1735671310.7724044, 1735671312.1758883, 1735671313.3797104, 1735671314.3440118]
I would like help with this not per se with only code but I would love to know how to calculate this.

For the average of people entering, divide the number of people by the number of minutes from the first entering to the last entering. For the average of people leaving, you would also need to record the time when they leave, and then do the same.

First of, thanks. how would you calculate it with only 1 person in the queue? just use 1 minute?

When there is only one person, this calculation makes no sense.

Averages are tricky. Assuming you want the rolling average, you'll need to decide how long you want to average over. You could imagine that if you wanted to average over each second, most seconds would have 0 people/minute, and a few would have 60/minute—not exactly helpful.
Keeping that in mind, let's assume you want to average over a period of one minute. For the number of people entering the queue, that's the same as asking how many people entered the queue in the last minute. You can iterate through the queue and count that, like so:
AVERAGING_TIME = 60.0 # In seconds

# Move backward through the list, until we reach the end of it, or a time more than a minute ago
current_time = time.time()
count = 0
i = len(times) - 1
while i >= 0 and current_time - times[i] < AVERAGING_TIME:
    count += 1
    i -= 1

average_entrances = count / AVERAGING_TIME * 60.0

For the exits, you would need a second queue, just like this one, but with the exit times. You can remove entries once they are old enough, and use the count to calculate the average.

To calculate the average number of people entering and leaving a queue per minute, follow these steps:
When a person enters, append their timestamp:
queue.append(time.time())

When a person leaves, record the exit time:
exit_time = time.time()
# Store exit times in a separate list if needed

Calculate Average Entries Per Minute

Calculate Time Span:
total_time = (queue[-1] - queue[0]) / 60  # Total time in minutes


Count Entries:
entries_count = len(queue)  # Total entries
avg_entries_per_minute = entries_count / total_time



Count Exits (if you have a list of exit times):
exits_count = len(exit_times)  # Total exits
avg_exits_per_minute = exits_count / total_time

This will give you the average number of people entering and leaving the queue per minute.
